# expo proxy config, web api call

Tags: api, http, react-native, proxy, expo

I am doing an API call within react native like this:

`let response = await fetch('localhost:5000/api/klant/1');`

And i want to do

`let response = await fetch('/api/klant/1');`

With react native it is possible to set a proxy conf at package.json. I was wondering if this is also possible with an detached expo app.

example of package.json

`{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "expokit": "^32.0.7",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "proxy": "localhost:5000",
  "private": true
}`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you should just allow cors request since you are in a react-native environment, and you cannot preddict the network in production. This will solve your issue for both native and web development

Answer (score 1):

The web service of expo is based on webpack and expo provides a way to customize the webpack config: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-webpack

In you example, you can create the webpack.config.js like the document says. Then set the proxy:

```js
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);

  config.devServer = {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
    }
  }

  return config;
};
```

It will poxy any request to `/api/**/*` to 5000 port.